# Importing slick carousel theme css throws errors on webpack build

Tags: webpack, sass, slick.js

I'm trying to import `slick-theme.scss` in my parent scss as

`@import "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";`

but during bundle, I get errors on the files imported in `slick-theme.scss`. Here's the error log

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./sass/app.scss
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ajax-loader.gif' in '/Users/Vishal/Documents/Work/nf-core/sass'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./sass/app.scss 6:89679-89707
```

I tried adding `resolve-url-loader` as well to the webpack configuration, but that doesn't help.

Here's my webpack scss loader section

```
loaders: commonConfig.module.loaders.concat({
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
    })
})
```

Answer (score 27):

The solution by Roberto Alicata works, but can be achieved easier and without an additional file. Just add these two variables before importing slick:

```
$slick-font-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/fonts/";
$slick-loader-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/";

@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick', '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme';
```

The other variables don't cause problems and the `!default` flag is used to define a default value **to be overwritten**, not to overwrite it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I also had to add .gif and font loaders to my webpack config.

Answer (score 6):

create a file .scss (i.e. fix-slick.scss ) and write:

```
$slick-font-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/fonts/" !default;
$slick-font-family: "slick" !default;
$slick-loader-path: "~slick-carousel/slick/" !default;
$slick-arrow-color: black !default;
```

now, import this file from your main scss file.

Comment: this is returning ```http://localhost:8081/~slick-carousel/slick/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)```

my main.scss

```@import "_fix-slick";
 @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss";
 @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss";```

Answer (score 3):

CSS loaders will also return resources referenced with `@import 'other.css'` or `background-image: url("/images/loader.gif")` back to the webpack module tree.

"`Can't resolve './ajax-loader.gif'`" sounds like there are issues with resolving the path to the gif. 
 I don't think it should start with a `.`
CSS loaders usually expect paths to start with a character (filename), `/` for absolute and `~` for non-relative paths (webpack feature). Is this an error in slick-theme.scss?

It would also be useful to add the file-loader or url-loader to handle gif/png/jpg files.
Mainly to take them out of node_modules into your dist/release folder.

Comment: Yes, its an error in `slick-theme.scss`. And, i already have url-loader etc defined in my webpack config

Comment: @slam You can have your own version of `slick-theme.scss` in your project and edit it.

Comment: @slam To our luck slick uses variables to define those paths, if you import the SASS file you can fix the error with two variables. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the the limit to 4180 in webpack.config.js did the trick to me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of **Fabian von Ellerts** is correct, but in my case I needed to change  the path.

```
$slick-font-path: "~slick-slider/slick/fonts/";
$slick-loader-path: "~slick-slider/slick/";
```

Note: I'm using Storybook

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on a NextJS site. I found that removing the following CSS from the `slick-theme.min.css` file worked:

```
.slick-loading .slick-list{background:url(ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff}

@font-face {
    font-family: slick;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(fonts/slick.eot);
    src: url(fonts/slick.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
      url(fonts/slick.woff) format("woff"),
      url(fonts/slick.ttf) format("truetype"),
      url(fonts/slick.svg#slick) format("svg");
  }
```

I don't know where people are getting the fonts file from(?)