# Can't load slick-carousel in Rails + webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

While trying to load slick-carousel css files via webpacker, the following error is thrown during compilation:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/frontend.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./app/javascript/packs/frontend.sass)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/slick.woff'
```

The frontend was originally created using CRA and was working fine, but after migrating to webpacker this error started to show.

app/javascript/packs/frontend.sass:

```
@import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this now and found a fix by doing this(notice the `~` its supposed to point to the `node_modules` folder):

```
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';
```

I then followed this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884460

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Import style/js files

```js
import "slick-carousel";
```

```css
@import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
@import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';
```